# Order before CONCAT_WS

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a table with 3 Phone columns, I need to run some magic trying to get some records where the phone numbers could match between them, the problem is a Phone number could be on different field between the 2 records.

So I think that a canonical string with the 3 phone numbers should allow me to make the comparison, the problem is the canonizing process. Is there a way to do this? I'm adding a snippet to illustrate what I need to do.

Table is:

```
╔═════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID  ║  Phone1  ║  Phone2  ║  Phone3  ║
╠═════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 123 ║ 555-1234 ║ 666-1235 ║          ║
║ 124 ║ 666-1235 ║          ║ 555-1234 ║
║ 125 ║ 555-8520 ║ 777-7410 ║ 444-9999 ║
╚═════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

The result I'd be looking for is

```
╔═════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║ ID  ║         ConcatPhones         ║
╠═════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║ 123 ║ 555-1234||666-1235           ║
║ 124 ║ 555-1234||666-1235           ║
║ 125 ║ 444-9999||555-8520||777-7410 ║
╚═════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

Is there anyway I can do this with a simple variation of CONCAT_WS or a highly efficient stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work, if the values are indeed NULL and not blank:

```
select id,
       concat_ws('||', Phone1, Phone2, Phone3)
from t
```

The reference is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

> CONCAT_WS() does not skip empty strings. However, it does skip any
>   NULL values after the separator argument.

To handle ordering, I would go for:

```
select id,
       group_concat(phone Separator '||' order by phone) as ConcatPhones
from (select t.id,
             (case when nums.n = 1 then phone1
                   when nums.n = 2 then phone2
                   when nums.n = 3 then phone3
              end) as phone
       from t cross join
            (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) nums
     ) p
where phone is not null
group by id
```

This will filter out any id that doesn't have a phone number.

You can also do this with a giant `case` statement, although that seems something of a nightmare:

```
select t.id,
       (case when phone1 < phone2 and phone2 < phone3 then concat_ws('||', phone1, phone2, phone3)
             when phone1 < phone3 and phone3 < phone2 then concat_ws('||', phone1, phone3, phone2)
              . . .  through the remaining 4 permuatiations when all three are present
             when phone1 is null and phone2 < phone3 then concat_ws('||', phone2, phone3)
             . . . through the remaining 5 permutuations when one is NULL
             when phone1 is null and phone2 is null then phone3
              . . . through the remaining 2 permutations when two are NULL
        end) as ConcatPhones
from t
```

This is more efficient.  It is feasible for 3 phone numbers.  I wouldn't want to deal with, say, five of them.

Comment: This won't help me canonize my string, just a simple concatenation, I need Phone1, Phone2 and Phone3 ordered before the concatenation happens

Comment: If you have only 3 fields you can 'sort' them using CASE or some IF's. Its not gonna look pretty...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: AWESOME... though I have to stick to the CASE nightmare as this is only part of a MUCH larger and very heavy query already, so I don't want toss another join in there if I can avoid it.