# Update field with other fields values alphabetically sorted

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table ("mytable") with some string fields ("p1, p2... p6").

I have empty fields called plA and plB that I want to UPDATE.

plA must contain the concatenation of the values of p1, p2 and p3 sorted alphabetically and separated by commas.

plB must contain the concatenation of the values of p4, p5 and p6 sorted alphabetically and separated by commas.

Here you have a portion of mytable and the wanted result:

```
 p1     p2     p3     p4     p5     p6     
 "tpa"  "rst"  "abc"  "cba"  "rpt"  "klw"
 "mtb"  "adr"  "aab"  "mav"  "bad"  "goo"
```

I want to UPDATE the table and plA and plB must contain:

```
 plA              plB
 "abc,rst,tpa"    "cba,klw,rpt"
 "aab,adr,mtb"    "bad,goo,mav"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that the values are all different and never `NULL`, you can do this with a bit of comparison logic:

```
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',
                 LEAST(p1, p2, p3),
                 (CASE WHEN p1 NOT IN ( LEAST(p1, p2, p3), GREATEST(p1, p2, p3) ) THEN p1
                       WHEN p2 NOT IN ( LEAST(p1, p2, p3), GREATEST(p1, p2, p3) ) THEN p1
                       ELSE p3
                  END),
                 GREATEST(p1, p2, p3)
                ) AS ps,
        CONCAT_WS(',',
                 LEAST(p4, p5, p6),
                 (CASE WHEN p4 NOT IN ( LEAST(p4, p5, p6), GREATEST(p4, p5, p6) ) THEN p4
                       WHEN p5 NOT IN ( LEAST(p4, p5, p6), GREATEST(p4, p5, p6) ) THEN p5
                       ELSE p6
                  END),
                 GREATEST(p4, p5, p6)
                ) AS ps
FROM ...
```

I should emphasize that the data structure just looks wrong.  You should be storing each "p" value on a separate row.

Also, this does not scale well beyond 3 values.

Comment: What happened to group_concat with order? is least/greatest faster?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773804/order-before-concat-ws

Comment: p1 to p10 represent different players being active in a basketball game. Every row is a play at the game, so I can't store each p on a different row. I'd need to use the answer to more than 3 p's.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ive changed p25 to p5 then it should work without errors.

Comment: Any hints for more than 3 p's (let's say 5 of them)?

Comment: @Javi . . . Please ask *another* question.  This question is clearly about groups of 3.  Groups of 5 would be handled a bit differently.